# Rewrite URL using htaccess : Convert url slug to url parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect `www.abc.com/pqr/xyz/` to `www.abc.com/pqr/?param=xyz`

I gave a try with the following :

```
RewriteRule "^pqr/(.+)/$" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pqr/?param=$1"  [L]
```

I suspect that above rewrite rule is making an infinite loop.

Please help to do the rewrite correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Rewrite Rules in .htaccess file:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^pqr\/([^\/]+)\/?$"  "/pqr/?param1=$1" [L]
```

Comment: what error do you get @MallikarjunM? It works fine on my local machine.

Comment: I am working on htaccess for a website. It's getting redirected to the home page.

Comment: Check, if there exists another .htaccess in /pqr directory? You can try the above rules at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=e7d2f694-6ce2-53e9-b768-f62881961805 online. It seems working fine.

Comment: there is no /pqr directory, and thank you for the link, never came across that before. accepting the answer for the link you shared.

Comment: So in `"%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pqr/?` which page is serving the request? Are you able to fetch resource using `www.abc.com/pqr/?param=xyz` link?

Comment: I am able to fetch the page using www.abc.com/pqr/?param=xyz. The website is using wordpress framework. pqr is a page which is loading through a .php file.